# Activity has been destroyed во время FragmentTransaction.commit()

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment

Пишу небольшую программку для андроида. Мне нужно создать программно фрагменты. Для этого я написал отдельный класс с функциями
FragmentWorkHelper.java:

```
public class FragmentWorkHelper extends FragmentActivity {

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft;
public MainTopCompositeFragment mtcf = new MainTopCompositeFragment();
public MainCentralCompositeFragment mccf = new MainCentralCompositeFragment();
public MainBottomCompositeFragment mbcf = new MainBottomCompositeFragment();


public void ReplaceFrag(Fragment f, int container){
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(container, f);
    ft.commit();
}

public void RemoveFrag(Fragment f){
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(f);
    ft.commit();
}

public void AddFrag(Fragment f, int container){
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(container, f);
    ft.commit();
}

public void CreateFrag(){
    ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_top_fragment, mtcf);
    ft.add(R.id.main_central_fragment, mccf);
    ft.add(R.id.main_bottom_fragment, mbcf);
    ft.commit();
} }
```

Вызываю функции этого класса из различных мест программы, например в OnCreate() в MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentWorkHelper fwh = new FragmentWorkHelper();
    fwh.CreateFrag(); }
```

Но в итоге получаю вот что:

```
Process: developers.com.polygon, PID: 27767
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{developers.com.polygon/developers.com.polygon.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1399)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:637)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:616)
        at developers.com.polygon.FragmentWorkHelper.CreateFrag(FragmentWorkHelper.java:43)
        at developers.com.polygon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
```

В чем беда? Почему активити уничтожается? Я пытался засунуть функции в MainActivity, но выходит та же самая ошибка. Очень нужна помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getSupportFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) возвращает менеджер для взаимодействия фрагментов с activity из которой он вызван. Соответственно ваш хелпер бесполезен т.к. он может управлять фрагментами только внутри своей `activity`, а не во всех `activity` вашего приложения. Если хелпер вам так нужен то сделайте так

```
public class FragmentWorkHelper{

    private final FragmentActivity activity;

    public FragmentWorkHelper(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void replaceFrag(Fragment f, int container){
        FragmentTransacion ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //some work
    }

    public void removeFrag(Fragment f){
        FragmentTransacion ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //some work
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment f, int container){
        FragmentTransacion ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //some work
    }
}
```

И тогда в `activity` в методе `onCreate()` создавайте экземпляр этого хелпера `FragmentWorkHelper helper = new FragmentWorkHelper(this)`.

Comment: Спасибо! Видимо не дочитал про getSupportFragmentManager, все работает отлично.